# Does Windows have a unique key/fingerprint, that won't go away after reinstallation?

Tags: java, windows, unique

I have a question that I couldn't find an answer online, so I decided to ask here.

1. Does Windows have a "Unique Identifier" per PC? That's not the CD-Key? If so:

   1a. Is it possible to get and use that Identifier, legally?

   1b. If I were to reinstall my PC, would that Identifier change? Or could I change it manually?

If not:

2. Is it possible to create a "Unique Identifier" that..

   2a. Stays the same, even after reinstalling my PC?

   2b. That can't be deleted/changed?

Comment: I don't know, but you might want to think about what defines a "PC" to you?   What if I replace my cpu?  My network card?  My mother board?   My hard drive?   When is it a new PC?

Comment: I realize that it wouldn't be 100% fool proof, but just trying to get as close as possible to it.

In all honesty, I don't know what it'll be for. I just wanted try something that's beyond my skills and something that I could really "sink my teeth into".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to calculate the unique identifier from the hardware e.g. by reading drive serial number or network card MAC address. Reading this will usually require to execute a native command from Java e.g. on Linux to read drive serial number you have to:

```
udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda | grep ID_SERIAL
```

Do remember that this identifiers can be changed by the user but in fairness so can anything else. If the users wants to spoof the identifier they will find a way.

Comment: Also recall that people _do_ replace disk drives and even network controllers.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it.